# CodeIgniter mp4 file upload is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, mp4

i am trying to upload a mp4 file with CodeIgniter but it is not working.

it shows me an error message.

**you didn't select a file to upload**

and the same code is working fine with .png type images.

i changed my php.ini max upload size and post data size as per my requirement.I also added mime type for mp4 into mime.php file of the CodeIgniter:

**'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',**

i also tried

**'mpeg4'   =>  'video/mpeg4',**

here is my controller code

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|flv|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '500000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

so please suggest some solution for this issue.

-Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Do you name input field like this?

   `<input type="file" name="userfile" />`

If not, you have to specify in.

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

the name of file input.

2.Is your form like this?

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="controller/function" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You can read more here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score -3):

i got the solution the code is correct and working fine.

this the issue with particular mp4 file.

i need to check the mime type of that file.